# HashMap : Find a Value from a Key from different class

Tags: java, hashmap

first take a look of my code so far here:
main program

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    KamusService service = new KamusService(); 
    IKamus idKeEn = new IDKeEN(); 
    String artiBelajar = service.cariArtiKata("belajar",idKeEn);
    String artiPintu = service.cariArtiKata("pintu",idKeEn);
    System.out.println(artiBelajar);
    System.out.println(artiPintu);
}
```

KamusService class

```
public class KamusService {

public String cariArtiKata(String cariArtiKata, IKamus n) {

    return n.terjemahkan();
}
```

idKeEn class

```
public class IDKeEN extends IKamus {
Map<String,String> id2en = new HashMap<String,String>();

public IDKeEN() {
    id2en.put("belajar","learning");
    id2en.put("pintu","door");
}

@Override
public String terjemahkan() {
    return id2en.get("pintu");
    }       
}
```

and IKamus class

```
public abstract class IKamus {
public abstract String terjemahkan();
```

}

i wonder how to put "belajar" from `String artiBelajar` to my HashMap inside IDKeEN class as a key so main program can print `String artiBelajar`

From above you can see that my program's output is "door" because inside IDKeEN class it override the output. 
i just wanna know how to make this line work

```
String artiBelajar = service.cariArtiKata("belajar",idKeEn);
```

use "belajar" as a Key for my HashMap and idKeEn as the destination class to process the whole things.

Thanks.

Comment: `IKamus idKeEn = new IDKeEN("belajar");` And then use that string in the constructor of `IDKeEN` to `put()` in the hashmap

Comment: `terjemahkan` needs to take a `String` parameter from the service

Comment: @RafiduzzamanSonnet i got main program is like that. i just need to make class that makes main program work.

Comment: @4castle i think so but how?

Comment: `public String terjemahkan(String s) { return id2en.get(s); }`

Comment: @4castle lol it works. i just add your code and do a couple change to class `IKamus` and also couple change in class `KamusService` and it works. thanks man.